Eigenvalues of block tridiagonal matrix with zeros on the main diagonal.
The given $n\times n$ matrix is a Hamiltonian (H) for an open boundary system. where $A=\begin{pmatrix}
tc1 & -v2 \\
v1 & -tf1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}
tc2 & -v1 \\
v2 & -tf2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$.
I am looking for eigenvalue and eigenvectors of the given Hamiltonian in a closed form. Thanks.
$$ 
H = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & A & 0 & 0 & \dots \\
A^{T} & 0 & B & 0 & \dots \\
0 & B^{T} & 0 & A & \dots \\
0 & 0 & A^{T} & 0 & \dots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\   
\end{pmatrix}_{n\times n}
$$

Can you elaborate on your question and show what you are thinking? I suggest you see this article How to ask a good question
